# Pagination in DynamoDB nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am wondering how could I paginate in AWS Dynamodb database in the most efficient way possible. I have found a few solutions playing with the `ExclusiveStartKey` like this:

```js
var params = {  
        "TableName"                 : "abcd",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames"  : {"#someexperssion":"someexperssion"},
        "ExpressionAttributeValues" : {":someexperssion" : "value"},
        "Limit"                     : 20,
        "ExclusiveStartKey"         : {"id": "9ee10f6e-ce6d-4820-9fcd-cabb0d93e8da"}
    };
```

The problem I found with these solutions is that You always have to know the last key `ExclusiveStartKey`. When I only want to retrieve the 4th page with a 10 items, do I have to query all the items before the 4th page to know what is the last key?

I would like to access the db only once when trying to get the nth page. Is that possible?

Thank You all!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could implement your own custom pagination using a global secondary index for your application's read mechanism. Having a GSI dedicated for reading paged data will eliminate the need to read prior pages in DynamoDB's native implementation.

The downside of this is that you have to implement a reliable paging system and it might offer challenges in terms of grouping which batch should be grouped together, if its not much a pain for your team to work on and time for development is not an issue, might be what you are looking for.